# Different colors for Keys and Values for JSON?

Tags: json, syntax-highlighting, komodo, komodoedit

I was wondering if there is a way to color keys and values differently for JSON files. So far I have only found the "String" property to have any effect, but it changes both the key and the value simultaneously.

Comment: do you have the ability to create/define properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both keys and values are usually strings in JSON (not in javascript objects though), there's no way to highlight them differently. However, you can [file an enhancement request on the bug tracker](https://github.com/komodo/komodoedit/issues) for this.